# BQ command line: Query too large

Tags: google-bigquery

i am running a query from command line to store in a new table. In this query I have several subqueries, each accessing multiple tables with TABLE_DATE_RANGE.

For each table stub there is one table per day. SO there are 4 subqueries, each accessign 180 Tables (90 days in two TABLE_DATE_RANGE queries). This amounts to 720 Tables total. So I should not max out the 1k table limit.

I have maxed out the 1k table limit before and got an error stating "too many tables" or similar.

This query however gives me the error "Query too large". As you can see below, I do allow large results. Does anyone know a solution to this?

```
bq query -n0 --allow_large_results --replace --destination_table="cdate-prod:crm_adhoc.tmp_email_details_event_date" 'select event_date
,contact_id
,message_name
,message_name_join
,message_id
,email
,REGEXP_EXTRACT(email,r'([^@]*$)') as email_domain
,REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(email,r'([^@]*$)'),r'(^[^\.]*)') as email_provider
,sent
,sent_unique_hlp
,open
,open_unique_hlp
,open_unique_msg_hlp
,click
,click_unique_hlp
,click_unique_msg_hlp
,soft_bounce
,medium_bounce
,hard_bounce
,activity
,type
,case when type = 1 then 'PPM' 
      when type = 2 then 'NPM' 
      when type = 3 then 'PENDING' 
      when type = 4 then 'CB' 
      when type = 5 then 'REDEBIT' 
      when type = 6 then 'INTCO' 
      when type = 7 then 'EXTCO' 
      else 'XX' 
 end as type_str
from 

(select send_date  as event_date
,contact_id
,message_name
,substr(message_name,7) as message_name_join
,message_id
,email
, 1 as sent
, contact_id as sent_unique_hlp
, 0 as open
, string('') as open_unique_hlp
, string('') as open_unique_msg_hlp
, 0 as click
, string('') as click_unique_hlp 
, string('') as click_unique_msg_hlp
, 0 as soft_bounce
, 0 as medium_bounce
, 0 as hard_bounce
, IFNULL(activity,0) as activity
, IFNULL(type,0) as type
from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(crm_data.campaign_messages,date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-90,"day"),date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day")),
     TABLE_DATE_RANGE(crm_data.interface_messages,date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-90,"day"),date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day"))) ms,

(select open_date as event_date
,contact_id
,message_name
,substr(message_name,7) as message_name_join
,message_id
,email
, 0 as sent
, string('')as sent_unique_hlp
, 1 as open
, contact_id as open_unique_hlp
, concat(contact_id,string(TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(send_date))) open_unique_msg_hlp
, 0 as click
, string('') as click_unique_hlp 
, string('') as click_unique_msg_hlp
, 0 as soft_bounce
, 0 as medium_bounce
, 0 as hard_bounce
, IFNULL(activity,0) as activity
, IFNULL(type,0) as type
from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(crm_data.interface_openings,date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-90,"day"),date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day")),
     TABLE_DATE_RANGE(crm_data.campaign_openings,date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-90,"day"),date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day"))) op,

(select click_date as event_date 
,contact_id
,message_name
,substr(message_name,7) as message_name_join
,message_id
,email
, 0 as sent
, string('')as sent_unique_hlp
, 0 as open
, string('') as open_unique_hlp
, string('') as open_unique_msg_hlp
, 1 as click
, contact_id as click_unique_hlp 
, concat(contact_id,string(TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(send_date))) click_unique_msg_hlp
, 0 as soft_bounce
, 0 as medium_bounce
, 0 as hard_bounce
, IFNULL(activity,0) as activity
, IFNULL(type,0) as type
from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(crm_data.interface_clicks,date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-90,"day"),date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day")),
     TABLE_DATE_RANGE(crm_data.campaign_clicks,date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-90,"day"),date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day"))) cl,

(select bounce_date as event_date
,contact_id
,message_name
,substr(message_name,7) as message_name_join
,message_id
,email
, 0 as sent
, string('')as sent_unique_hlp
, 0 as open
, string('') as open_unique_hlp
, string('') as open_unique_msg_hlp
, 0 as click
, string('') as click_unique_hlp 
, string('') as click_unique_msg_hlp
,case when bounce_category = 1 then 1 end soft_bounce
,case when bounce_category = 2 then 1 end medium_bounce
,case when bounce_category in (3,4,5) then 1 end hard_bounce
, IFNULL(activity,0) as activity
, IFNULL(type,0) as type
from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(crm_data.interface_bounces,date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-90,"day"),date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day")),
     TABLE_DATE_RANGE(crm_data.campaign_bounces,date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-90,"day"),date_add(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day"))) bo'

Waiting on bqjob_r71fbdcc95fa950e5_0000014f82f52d18_1 ... (0s) Current status: RUNNING 
Waiting on bqjob_r71fbdcc95fa950e5_0000014f82f52d18_1 ... (1s) Current status: RUNNING 
Waiting on bqjob_r71fbdcc95fa950e5_0000014f82f52d18_1 ... (1s) Current status: DONE   
Error in query string: Error processing job
'cdate-prod:bqjob_r71fbdcc95fa950e5_0000014f82f52d18_1': Query too large
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, from what I know:

- A query can only be up to x characters long. The query presented here is shorter than that, but...
- TABLE_DATE_RANGE works by internally expanding the query to contain explicitly all the in-range table names. This is usually fine, but...
- This query refers to 720 tables. The query will be expanded by explicitly mentioning 720*length(table_name). That pushes it over the limit.

Suggestion: Could you union older tables into monthly entities instead of daily ones?

Comment: I see your point. I can split the subqueries first and then append into the table. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the expansion of the TABLE_DATE_RANGE clause caused the query text to become too large as you suggested. I split the one Query into 4. The first query is run with the `--replace` flag and the other three afterwards with the `--append` flag.

Comment: Felipe is correct that all of those limits exist, but the one you hit is actually an internal RPC limit when passing around the data contained in those tables. The workaround is the same, but hopefully we'll be able to handle this case in the future with some changes on the BQ side.